# Integrate Jquery plugin into CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Ok i wanna integrate jquery into codeIgniter view file, and i have trouble put my jquery plugin into right place.

in view file my code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul.youtube-videogallery").youtubeVideoGallery( {assetFolder:'localhost/yt'} );


    });
</script>
```

I made folder called yt in my root file htacces/rip/yt - and put plug in into it. How to write {assetFolder:'localhost/yt'} in correct way. My plugin isnt working. So help me to taret assets folder???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your CI-directory is localhost (that is, not a subfolder of localhost):

```
{assetFolder:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>yt'}
```